# How can i serve domain subfolder from different Apache 2 server?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, directory

1. Squid 3 reverse proxy is pointin to 80.241.222.151 for domain http:// www.megasity.com
2. Apache 2 server is on 80.241.222.151 with all files in the root folder so all requests are served from here
3. Now im creating new server at 80.241.222.149 with all files from http:// www.megasity.com/elenadamer transfered to the root
4. On Squid 3 server http:// www.megasity.com is still pointing to 80.241.222.151
5. But now i need to call http:// www.megasity.com/elenadamer from 80.241.222.149 in the root.

What is the example to do this? mod_proxy on Apache 2 server at 80.241.222.151? Please, give me an good answer. Thanx for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the 80.241.222.151 you could try something like the following

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /elenadamer/ http://80.241.222.149/
ProxyPassReverse /elenadamer/ http://80.241.222.149/
```

Comment: Is this in apache2.conf, or in default site config? Thanx.

Comment: I tried to a2enmod proxy, then restart apache2, added your lines into default site available file, but im getting 500 internal server error. What am i still missing?

Comment: I ried to put this into proxy.conf of mods-available within apache2, even within .htaccess. But have the same error 500. Please, help. I would really like to offload this from this server.

Comment: What does the apache log say when you get the 500 server error?